# Kafka to zookeeper DIGEST-MD5 authentication error

Tags: security, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, hortonworks-data-platform, sasl

I could able to do DIGEST-MD5 authentication with kafka broker and embedded zookeeper which is given by Kafka but I was getting following error message while doing DIGEST-MD5 authentication with Kafka broker and non embedded zookeeper (separate zookeeper instance).

Please find below is the error message:

```
[2018-11-05 19:44:21,536] ERROR SASL authentication failed using login context 'Client' with exception: {} (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)

javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Error in authenticating with a Zookeeper Quorum member: the quorum member's saslToken is null.

org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$AuthFailedException: KeeperErrorCode = AuthFailed for /consumers
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your jaas files look like ?

For Zookeeper cluster, you must have three sections in zookeeper jaas file : 
**Server**, **QuorumServer** and **QuorumLearner**

**QuorumServer** and **QuorumLearner** sections are used to authenticate zookeeper servers to each other. See example of configuration [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/Server-Server+mutual+authentication) in §*DIGEST-MD5 based authentication*

**Server** section is used to authenticate kafka brokers. It should contains kafka username and password formatted as shown [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/Client-Server+mutual+authentication) in §*Server Configuration/ JAAS configuration file: DIGEST-MD5 authentication*

Your Kafka jaas file should have a **Client** section with a username and a password as shown [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/Client-Server+mutual+authentication) in §*Client Configuration / JAAS configuration file: DIGEST-MD5 authentication*

Finally, check that you are using correct environment variable for zookeeper jaas file :

```
SERVER_JVMFLAGS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/server/jaas/file.conf"
```

Embedded zookeeper uses KAFKA_OPTS

Comment: Now I have enabled authorization and While creating topic getting the error i.e., Error while executing topic command : KeeperErrorCode = NoAuth for /config/topics/test ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoAuthException: KeeperErrorCode = NoAuth for /config/topics/test

Comment: Seems good, you don't have access to your topic, you can now play with [acl](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_authz). You will have to do export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=admin_jaas.conf"  with a jaas file containing a Client section before using kafka-acls.sh

Comment: Same thing I have done then it's working fine and if I use two zookeepers then what are the problems will I get?

Comment: apart from you need an [odd number of zookeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkMulitServerSetup), it should work.

Comment: Ok Thanks. As per documentation, I have done zookeeper cluster with 3 nodes and for example, one zookeeper node went down, then what will happen for read and write cases?