# Kafka receive Sasl Exception from Zookeeper when SASL Authentication enabled

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to set up an open-source Kafka cluster. Cluster is comprised of 2 Kafka nodes and 1 zookeeper. When I tried to enabled zookeeper SASL authentication, I got below exception. Providing Zookeeper and Kafka configuration files. Please help me where I am doing wrong.

```
ERROR SASL authentication failed using login context 'Client' with exception: {} (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Error in authenticating with a Zookeeper Quorum member: the quorum member's saslToken is null.
at org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient.createSaslToken(ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:279)
at org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient.respondToServer(ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:242)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.readResponse(ClientCnxn.java:805)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:94)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:366)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1145)
```

**My Zookeeper settings as below**

1) zookeeper_jaas.conf

```
Server {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useKeyTab=true
storeKey=true
keyTab="/tmp/zookeeper.service.keytab"
principal="zookeeper/<<Zookeeper-SERVER-INTERNAL-DNS>>@EXAMPLE.COM";
};
```

2) zookeeper.properties

```
dataDir=/home/ubuntu/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
maxClientCnxns=0

authProvider.1=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
jaasLoginRenew=3600000
```

3) export "ZOOKEEPER_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/ubuntu/kafka/config/zookeeper_jaas.conf"

4) created ticket using zookeeper Keytab

5) Started the zookeeper server successfully which binds at the port 2181.

**Kafka broker settings**

1) kafka_server_jaas.conf

```
KafkaServer {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=true
    storeKey=true
    keyTab="/tmp/kafka.service.keytab"
    principal="kafka/<<KAFKA-SERVER-PUBLIC-DNS>>@EXAMPLE.COM";
};

Client {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=true
    storeKey=true
    servicename="zookeeper"
    keyTab="/tmp/kafka.service.keytab"
    principal="kafka/<<KAFKA-SERVER-PUBLIC-DNS>>@EXAMPLE.COM";
};
```

2) Kafka_client_jass.conf

```
KafkaClient {
 com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
 useTicketCache=true;
 };
```

3)server.properties

```
broker.id=0

listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092,SSL://0.0.0.0:9093,SASL_SSL://0.0.0.0:9094
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<<KAFKA-SERVER-PUBLIC-DNS>>:9092,SSL://<<KAFKA-SERVER-PUBLIC-DNS>>:9093,SASL_SSL://<<KAFKA-SERVER-PUBLIC-DNS>>:9094

zookeeper.connect=<<ZOOKEEPER-SERVER-PRIVATE-DNS>>:2181

sasl.enabled.mechanisms=GSSAPI
sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka

ssl.keystore.location=/home/ubuntu/ssl/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=serversecret
ssl.key.password=serversecret
ssl.truststore.location=/home/ubuntu/ssl/kafka.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=serversecret

ssl.client.auth=required

num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
auto.create.topics.enable=false
log.dirs=/home/ubuntu/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

4) export "KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/ubuntu/kafka/config/kafka_server_jaas.conf"

5) Created ticket using Kafka Keytab.

6) I started the Kafka broker and got the exception mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of ZOOKEEPER_OPTS use KAFKA_OPTS in zookeeper settings (point-3). This will work. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it's helped me too. It may be a mistake in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/Client-Server+mutual+authentication/ You should use `KAFKA_OPTS` instead of `SERVER_JVMFLAGS`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53156781/kafka-to-zookeeper-digest-md5-authentication-error